# Kernel function to set the PG_Referenced bit of a heap page

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a small C application shown below. It does the following operations:

1. Allocate two pages of heap memory.
2. Clear referenced bit (`PG_referenced`) of heap page (`echo 1 > /proc/pid/clear_refs`).
3. Do a write to the heap allocated pages again.
4. Check referenced bit is getting set in page after the write operation. (`cat /proc/pid/smaps`)
   *I found it is getting set.*
5. Repeat step 2 to 4 to verify correctness.

So from this exercise I understood whenever I do a write to the heap page, the `PG_referenced` bit is getting set, and whenever I clear it using `/proc/pid/clear_ref` it is getting cleared.

**So I looked in the kernel code to find out which kernel function is setting the `PG_referenced` bit. I thought it was the `mark_page_accessed()` function in `mm/swap.c`. But after searching I found some other function is setting the `PG_referenced` bit of the page for every write, if I clear it before write.**

**So, please some one, help me to find out which kernel function is doing this?**

I am writing down the application I used for testing:

```c
    ptr_obj = malloc(2*4096);

    while(1){
            /* clear all page refernces  */
            sprintf(buffer,"echo 1 > /proc/%d/clear_refs ",pid);
            system(buffer);

            /* move smaps to a file */
            sprintf(buffer,"cat /proc/%d/smaps > temp_before.%d",pid,count);
            system(buffer);

            /* do a  write to malloc addr */

            ptr_obj[1] = 12;;
            ptr_obj[6000] = 12;;

            /* move update smaps to file **/
            sprintf(buffer,"cat /proc/%d/smaps > temp_after.%d",pid,count);
            system(buffer);
            count ++;

            sleep(30);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

"Referenced" of /proc/pid/smaps indicates the amount of memory currently marked as referenced or accessed. It includes PG_referenced of the page flags and the ACCESSED_BIT set by the MMU in page table entry. The code of /proc/pid/smaps:

```
static void smaps_pte_entry(
    ......
        /* Accumulate the size in pages that have been accessed. */
        if (pte_young(ptent) || PageReferenced(page))
            mss->referenced += ptent_size;
```

`pte_young()` of the X86 test the ACCESSED_BIT of the PTE. This bit is set by MMU when your code writing in to the Heap.

Comment: Lai Jiangshan Thank you for your answer!!.But ACCESSED_BIT of PTE set for both read and write,Not only write.Basically it will set of access.I actually want to check is there any write happened to the page,So i want to differentiate read ,write from a kernel?,Is there any way for that ???

Answer (score 0):

Dhyan, if you *are asking* how to find the pages that are written (not accessed, which includes both read and write), then you should check out the `soft dirty bit`.

So, instead of `1`, write `4` in `clear_prefs`.

Check out official linux documentation:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/soft-dirty.txt

*you were asking, 2 years ago actually.